# Toggle disabled text input onclick

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, input, onclick

My code is working perfectly until the inputbox is disabled and onclick is not triggering anything when the inputbox is on disabled mode.

Pretty simple :)

html:

```
<input id=toggleMe>
```

javascript:

```
var toggleMe=document.getElementById("toggleMe");

toggleMe.onclick=function(){if(toggleMe.disabled==false){toggleMe.disabled=true;}else{toggleMe.disabled=false;}}
```

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/45cx6rwv/

Comment: lil emprovement here: you may get rid of `if` statements by `toggleMe.onclick=function(){toggleMe.disabled=!toggleMe.disabled}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not click on disabled elements. You can use a class instead based on which you can set the *readOnly* property of the element:

```js
document.getElementById('toggleMe').addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.classList.toggle("disabled");
  if(this.classList.value.includes('disabled')){
        this.readOnly = true;
    } else {
        this.readOnly = false;
    }
});
```

```css
.disabled{
    background-color: #DDD;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggleMe">
```

Comment: Cool Man! But I'm not using jQuery... :D

Comment: Is `this.classList.toggle("disabled")` would not be better solution?

Comment: @Hezi-Gangina there is no jquery.

Comment: @Hezi-Gangina, I mistakenly added that script....removed now....the solution is purely on JavaScript.